# Xcode Cannot find type 'WKWebView' in scope error on Xcode 12.5.1

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an app that uses WKWebView to display a website. However, when I run this (in ViewController.swift):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var WebsiteView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        WebsiteView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(WebsiteView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(WebsiteView.frame.height)\" src=\"http://example.com\"></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

it throws 2 errors. The main one is this:
`Cannot find type 'WKWebView' in scope`
The other one is this:
`'nil' requires a contextual type`.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Import a framework

Answer (score 1):

You need to import a Framework. Under `import UIKit` add

```
import WebKit
```